# Заполнение массива значениями из БД

Tags: java, база-данных, jdbc

Из базы данных надо получить и сохранить значения в двумерный массив `Object[][] data`. В нём должно быть (как и в таблице в БД) 4 столбца.

Я сделал так:

```
    try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            count = 0;

            while(rs.next()) {
                count++;
            }

            Object[][] data = new Object[count][4];
            count = 0;

            while(rs.next()) {  
                data[count][0] = rs.getString(1);
                data[count][1] = rs.getString(2);
                data[count][2] = rs.getString(3);
                data[count][3] = rs.getString(4);

                count++;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException se) {}
            try { stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException se) {}
            try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException se) {}
        }
```

Но `JAVA` выдаёт `NullPointerExeption`! Мои проверки выявили что значения в массиве все равны `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте данную строчку перед вторым циклом. При каждом вызове next() указатель смещается на следующий элемент и потому в конце он указывает в никуда и его необходимо сбросить в начало.

```
   rs.beforeFirst()
```